# What is the correct way to reply “What is the XXX”?

Tags: responses

What is the correct way to reply “What is the most expensive food in the market”?

Should I say:

1. The most expensive food is banana.
2. The banana is the most expensive food.
3. A banana is the most expensive food

Answer (score 1):

All of your answers are grammatical, and would work for a formal question.

Using a singular (*banana*) instead of a plural (*bananas*) is a little unusual, as people rarely buy a single banana. The sign at my grocery store uses the plural and says "Bananas 49¢ / pound."

The most common way to respond is simply to name the item:

> Bananas.

However, in many markets, *bananas* are inexpensive. So the *correct* answer might be

> Wagyu beef is the most expensive food.

Comment: 'A banana is the most expensive/popular food'  sounds bizarre in any register.  The generic plural is, I'd say, the overwhelmingly natural-sounding choice.

Comment: My wife is learning Korean from a textbook and discussing the answers with native Korean speakers. They will sometimes say, "the Korean is understandable, but nobody talks that way." *A banana is the most expensive food* is a textbook response, but nobody talks that way. *Bananas* (or *Wagyu beef*) is a response that native English speakers would actually use.

Comment: 'Beef' is of course non-count.